# jQuery iScroll clickable list elements while retaining scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iscroll

Is it possible to have clickable elements? Such as list elements? While using iScroll? Currently it seems like short of a button, or maybe a link I can't click on an element to make it do something. I had a similar issue with inputs as well. But with enough searching I was able to find a solution that helped me get to a place I could work with inputs. Now I have a need to have a scrollable ui while having the ability to click on something thats not a button or a link, such as a li contained within specific uls.

So I am wondering if there is a way of having iScroll tell the difference between a click or tap rather vs a scroll, and as such have it do the action desired.

Comment: and where is your related code??

Comment: which "related code" the list elements that are standard HTML? such as `<ul><li>abc</li><li>def</li></ul>`?

Comment: I wouldnt know whats relivant cause I can't find much outside of standard use for documentation on iScroll.. its currently configured like the doc's say to configure it, and everythings working accordingly, except I can't click on some element as the don't retain the event do to iScroll stealing the events essentially